# Ruby on rails: ActiveRecords' first_or_create is very slow

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I've got a ruby scripts which imports XML files to a MySQL database. It does it by looping through the elements in the XML file and finally

```
table.where(
          value:  e['value'],
          ...
      ).first_or_create
```

The script has to process a lot of data, most of it is already in the database. Because of this, it runs really slow because first_or_create obviously triggers a lot ot SELECT queries.

Is there any way to handle this more rapidly? Is it related to connection management?

Thanks

Comment: Can the XML file(s) contain the same element multiple times?

Comment: Is there an index for the clause you generate through the `where` command above?

Answer (score 0):

`first_or_create` is of course a convenience method, which doesn't much care about performance on a bigger data set.

Ensure all your indices are in place.

First obvious way to increase performance would be: since every create statement is wrapped in a `begin`, `commit` transaction block. Thats 3 queries for one insert.
You can place your whole loop inside `transaction` block - that will gain you some time as it will only execute `begin` and `commit` once.

Remember that the roundtrip to/from database takes considerable amount of time, so an obvious performance boost is to combine multiple statements into one. Try to create one `SELECT` query finding a batch of, let's say 1000 records. DB will return that 200 don't exist and you can go ahead and build one `INSERT` statement for those 200 queries.

Always perform measurements and always try to formulate what level of performance you are trying to achieve, to not make the code too verbose.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to eliminate records that need to create.check records if not in the db then create